# Unable to install eclipse on 12.10

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

After installing tomcat 6 on machine , my existing eclipse stops working and on ubuntu software center it showing the option to install eclipse. When I tried to install eclipse I am getting the following error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> eclipse-platform: Depends: eclipse-platform-data (>=
>   3.8.0~rc4-1ubuntu1) but 3.8.0~rc4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
>                     Depends: eclipse-rcp (= 3.8.0~rc4-1ubuntu1) but 3.8.0~rc4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
>                     Depends: liblucene2-java (< 2.9.5) but 2.9.4+ds1-4 is to be installed
>                     Depends: sat4j (< 2.4.0) but 2.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed

Any ideas to fix this ,

I got stuck in the middle of my work.

Comment: Install a newer version of Tomcat that isn't pulling in dependecies that are too old for Eclipse?

Comment: If possible You can directly download eclipse from eclipse.org and install

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Don't install Eclipse using a package manager. Just [download the tar.gz archive from eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) and unpack it anywhere. [3.8.2 is here.](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/)

Some background: Eclipse comes with its own package manager (p2). P2 doesn't like when someone else messes with its world. Linux package manager try to modify the p2 config files in such a way that p2 doesn't notice but eventually, this fails.

Word of advice: You can now install plugins using the help menu. **Every time you install a new plugin, make a backup of the Eclipse folder and your workspace.** P2 has some very ugly bugs and when it gets into a "I don't wanna work anymore" state, it's next to impossible to heal it.

Keep those backups in a safe place. You will eventually need them. And yes, I imply that you will need the 5th last backup eventually.

Note: To work, Eclipse just needs the files inside of its installation folder and in the `workspace/.metadata` folder. If they get damaged, it won't work anymore. That also means that installing packages using your package manager can't break Eclipse anymore.

Comment: The lastest version 4.2. You should use it instead.

Comment: @vinz243: ugn... no. The transition from 3.8 to 4.x is not smooth. If you have 3.8 now and you need to get back to work fast, don't try 4.2. It will just create new problems that you don't want to face right now.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla , thanks for replying . I have removed tomcat 6 and installed tomcat 7 reinstalled eclipse. After that eclipse start working . But only thing is I am not able to install tomcat 6 now .I have a project which is developed with tomcat 6. Is there any way to install tomcat 6

Comment: In that case, don't install Tomcat with your package manager. Just download and unpack it.